# Why "return <observable>" is not working?

Tags: angular, ionic4, rxjs-observables

I am working with Angular and WordPress rest API. Everything is going fine. But I have a little confusion with the behavior of the following code.

```
getpost(){
    return this.http.get('someURL');
}
```

The above function is residing in a service. When I try to subscribe to the returned observable, I get an error.
But the code below is working fine.

```
getpost(){
    let someVAR = this.http.get('someURL');
    return someVAR;
}
```

Please clarify **WHY** the above code is not returning observable. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working" and can you show us the surrounding code?

Comment: this snippet is residing in a serice. And I am not able to subscribe it from a component.

Comment: Please write full code. However, write subscribe after the http request

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
class PostService {
   public getpost(userId): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.apiurl + 'user/posts/' + userId);
      }
}

class MyClass implements OnInit {
      post: any;

      constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.userInformation = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getpost(userId).subscribe((posts) => {
          this.post = post;
        })
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing here will work. But in order to make the http call, you need to subscribe to that observable.

```
public getData() {
return this.http.get('someUrl');
}

export class MyComponent { 

constructor(private myService: MyService){}
usingData() {
this.myService.getData().subscribe(data => { // do stuff with the data  })
}
```

I'm not sure how you're currently using it but the above is how it should work.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Actually the function getData() resides in a service. And I need to subscribe to the observable from a component. I just want to know why the first line of my code is not returning the observable

Comment: @jailani it's supposed to work, you've got a bug somewhere that you're not seeing but that is the corect usage. I have updated my post with an example from a srevice

Answer (score 0):

Well here are some steps how to call http request using HttpClient:

> HttpClient using import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

and then you need to subcribe the observable (also you can use RxJS to do more with the observable).

```
constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
) { }

ngOnInit() { 
    // 2. Then you need to subscribe the observable
    this.getPost().subscribe(resp => {
       console.log("When success", resp);
    }, err => {
       console.log("When error", err);
    });
}

getPost() {
    return this.httpClient.get('someURL'); // 1. This will return the observable
}
```